# unable to login to kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.0.Final-jboss-as7.0

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I download the **kie-drools-wb-distribution-6.0.0.Final.zip** and deployed the **kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.0.Final-jboss-as7.0.war** in **jboss-as-7.1.1.Final** in standalone mode.
Now, when I'm tring to login using default username : admin password: admin. It's saying **Login failed: Invalid UserName or Password**

Log is showing this error message.

```
    17:38:30,683 ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password Incorrect/Password Required
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:270) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule.login(UsersRolesLoginModule.java:155) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:381) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
```

So, can anyone please tell me what to do??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this answer from Drools user community  [Ref: http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Drools-6-unable-to-login-to-kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6-0-0-Final-jboss-as7-0-td4027334.html#a4027335].

We just have to simply add an Application User in Jboss.

run the add-user.bat file under %JBOSS_HOME%\bin folder.

select Application User.
Then provide username, password and role.

See a example below:

```
    What type of user do you wish to add?
     a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties)
     b) Application User (application-users.properties)
    (a): b

    Enter the details of the new user to add.
    Realm (ApplicationRealm) :
    Username : tom
    Password :
    Re-enter Password :
    What roles do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated l
    ist, or leave blank for none) : admin
    About to add user 'tom' for realm 'ApplicationRealm'
    Is this correct yes/no? yes
    Added user 'tom' to file 'D:\Anijit\Software\jbpm-5.4.0.Final-installer-full\jbp
    m-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application-users.prop
    erties'
    Added user 'tom' to file 'D:\Anijit\Software\jbpm-5.4.0.Final-installer-full\jbp
    m-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\domain\configuration\application-users.properti
    es'
    Added user 'tom' with roles admin to file 'D:\Anijit\Software\jbpm-5.4.0.Final-i
    nstaller-full\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configuration\appli
    cation-roles.properties'
    Added user 'tom' with roles admin to file 'D:\Anijit\Software\jbpm-5.4.0.Final-i
    nstaller-full\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\domain\configuration\applicati
    on-roles.properties'
    Press any key to continue . . .
```